# How do I initialise an entire matrix with 0?

Tags: c

I want to initialise my matrix to 0, but it does not work because the first part of the matrix is a variable.

```
int playerCards[playerNum][10] = {0};
```

I want to make so all the values in the matrix are zero. I have tried the line above, but it tells me that i cannot initialise a the array. For reference, playerNum is an integer between 2 and 6, chosen by the user.

Comment: You said: _but it does not work_. Could you please __describe how it's not working__.

Comment: *it tells me*. Next time when asking about an error give the full and exact error message.

Comment: @kaylum Will do. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

You can use `memset()`:

```
int playerCards[playerNum][10];
memset(playerCards, 0, sizeof playerCards);
```

`sizeof` works for VLAs: in this case `playerCards` is evaluated, which does not make a difference, but also means that the size is computed at runtime as `sizeof(int) * playerNum * 10` using the value of `playerNum` at the time of instantiation of `playerCards`.

Comment: Can you actually use sizeof on a VLA?

Comment: @BillLynch "use sizeof on a VLA" --> yes.  It is evaluated at run-time.